# Hide/unhide empty rows button

Tags: button, hide, rows

I'm working on a Google Sheet for a crew to create per diems sheet for all of them. It's all automatic based on a start date.
The problem is;
My whole time period is three months. I have crew perhaps travelling only four days. Which means when I export an PDF for accounting they get a lot empty days.
I would really like to have a button to hide/unhide rows with no information in Column E. The problem is that I have no experience with scripts (as my Google search informs me i must have).
I once had a document that had this feature, but I did nok make it and it was Excel, macro I believe.

In my document I have 45 different sheets, all named from 1 to 45. If possible I could have a button for that hides rows in all sheets. If this button could be in a sheet called "Rules" that would be perfect. If no one knows a solution for this, a separate hide/unhide button for each sheet (1-45) would be perfect.

I'm asking a lot here, but hopefully someone that knows script a lot could make it a challenge to make my day.

I look forward for your replies.
In advance, thanks!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want? Of course, please remove your personal information. At that time, can you provide your current script? By this, we can also know about the language you want.